# looping through to first slide flexslider

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I'm using flexslider and I move from one slide to the next, I have 3 slides viewing at a time. When it reaches the last slide, I want it to continue showing slides if you keep clicking on the right arrow. Instead of stopping or jumping back to the first one, like a continuous loop. This doesn't seem to work.  Any ideas?

```
$(window).load(function(){
              $('.slides').fadeIn(600)  
              $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: true,
                itemWidth: 317,
                move: 1

              });
            });
```

Comment: This is currently an open issue with the flexslider: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/287

Answer (score 0):

Change flexlider with another slider :)
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/demos.php
This one can do the trick... See demo named "Carousel & Loop mode. Infinite Scrolling"